# What links "Luluco Space Patrol" and "Kill La Kill"?

Tags: kill-la-kill, space-patrol-luluco

In the episode 7 of the show *Luluco Space Patrol*, a lot of references to the anime *Kill La Kill* are made:

- The planet they are visiting is named *KLK* (initials for *Kill La Kill*)
- The characters are talking about living fibers and how it is necessary to use special scissors to cut them
- Some of the characters from *Kill La Kill* are present, such as the dog and the white clothes in background
- The "big excessive titles" we can see in *Kill La Kill* are present in this episode:

  [image: 宇宙ナントカ 詐欺現行犯]
- At 5:20, we can hear the main theme of *Kill La Kill*
- etc.

---

My question is: what links those two shows? Same editor/writer? What common points link those two anime close enough to  have an entire episode of *Luluco* dedicated to *Kill La Kill*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: what links those two shows? Same editor/writer?

Same everything, pretty much. Both shows are original IPs by [Trigger](http://www.st-trigger.co.jp/) (the animation studio), directed by studio founder Imaishi Hiroyuki, and I assume that many other staff members worked on both shows.

Trigger (or maybe it's just Imaishi) is known to be fond of reference humor - there were, for example, oblique references to *Kill la Kill* even in *Inou Battle wa Nichijou-kei no Naka de*, the latter of which was an adaptation of a non-Trigger IP. Given the opportunity to reference one of their own IPs from another of their own IPs - which means they don't have to tiptoe around copyright issues - the results are what you see in episode 7 of *Space Patrol Luluco*.

In addition to the *Kill la Kill* thing in episode 7, there's also *Little Witch Academia* in episode 8; *Sex & Violence with Machspeed* in episode 9; and *Inferno Cop* in episode 11. These three things are also original Trigger IPs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know what the "*IP*" term means...

Comment: In this context, what I mean by "an original IP" is something like "a show and its associated franchise for which intellectual property rights are held [by Trigger]". Likewise, "a non-Trigger IP" is "a show/etc for which intellectual property rights are not held by Trigger". This usage is a bit weird, I'll grant; I think it originates in discussions of video games, where something like "the Mario series" would be called "an IP" (from "intellectual property").

Comment: Ho, makes more sense! Thanks for your answer